# Summing multiple fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, summarizing

I have a layer/table with several fields I need to sum together to create a value in another field. I have tried using `aggregate()` and `sum()` but I can't get the a correct syntax to be able to do the calculation.

E.g. `"field6"` will equal:

```
sum("field1" + "field2" + "field3" + "field4" + "field5")
```

All fields are integer.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Attributes Form, click the field (which you have created as field type integer or decimal) and enter Default value:

```
"f1"+"f2"+"f3"
```

(using your field names)

And when I create a new feature with values 4,5,6 it automatically calculates 15:

[image]

Comment: In your example, are your fields all integer? My fields 1-5 are integer and using constraints with Value Map (E.g. Value1 = 0, Label1 = "A", Value2 = 2, Label2 = "B"). When 'labels are selected, resulting value populates field. Is this correct?

Comment: I have added 'required' on fields and wish to remove them now to test offered solutions but can't access the required table settings to remove 'required'. Sorry, but new to QGIS.

Comment: Yes they are all integers. Labels shouldnt matter,

Comment: I have set my fields to integer and used value maps to provide values to the table. When I add the fields together it is only listing each value as if concatenated (so in your example where it adds to 15, I am getting 456. If I change one field from value map to text edit or range then the sum works. Any ideas?

Comment: Was able to get calculation for integer fields working by using the following: to_int(  "f1"  )  +  to_int(  "f2"   )  +  to_int(  "f3"   )  +  to_int(  "f4"   )  +  to_int(  "f5"   ) otherwise value would only concatenate.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
"field1" + "field2" + "field3" + "field4" + "field5"
```

Comment: I tried that version as well, but it didn't work either. I wish to use this as an expression in a form widget. When applying test data, values are not calculating the final field.

Comment: Try to forget about widget and focus on learning the basics of software.

Comment: To understand the difference: `aggregate` as well as `sum` creates the sum for all features for a certain attribute like: value of `field1` of point1 + value of `field1` of point2 + value of `field1` of point3 etc.  Thus it calculates the sum of one single attribute per **column** for all points (or lines or polygons). What you want, however,  is the sum per **row**: value of `field1` of point1 + value of `field2` of point1 + value of `field3` of point1 etc., thus summing different attributes for the same poinz.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of attributes you want to sum up, there are alternatives to enumerating all of them (`value_1 + value_2 + value_3...`). Here are two possibilities to create the sum of `value_1 + ... + value_6` (see screenshot below). The function [`array_sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#array-sum) is [available since QGIS 3.18](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays).

1. For attributes with similar names (e.g. differing just in a number), create an array of the fieldnames by concatenating the stable part of the name + the variable part with `array_foreach()`:

```
   array_sum (
       array_foreach (
           generate_series (1,6,1),
              eval (
               'value_' || 
               @element
           )
       )
   )
```

2. For attribute-namess that differ a lot (no clear pattern), simply create an array of *all attribute names* using [`map_akeys(attributes( ))`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#map-akeys). In necessary, remove those field-names you want to skip (field `id` in this case):

```
   array_sum (
    array_foreach (
        array_remove_all( 
            map_akeys (
                attributes( )
            ), 
            'id'
        )
        ,
        eval(@element)
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: with both expressions, you get the same result: the sum from `value_1` to `value_6`, without the `id`:*
[image]

Comment: This looks like a handy function. Currently limited to using QGIS 3.16 for a 3rd party plug-in I am using.